# Tetbox value not getting updated?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox

I have an asp.net textbox which is disabled and I am setting the value for the textbox on client side using JQuery.

`$('[id$=txtCity]').val('Naperville');`

But the problem is when I am trying to save the data. If I say txtCity.Text it is not giving me the value that I set in the client side.

The textbox is disabled and I am seeing the value reflected in the textbox on the client side after the value is set using JQuery. But I am not sure why it is not reflected on the server side.

I found that TextBox with **disabled** will **not be submitted** with the form on postback. If that is true, how can I submit those values and get that on server side in the code behind.

Please help. Thanks and appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Tell us a bit more about why it's disabled. Does the user need to see it? Is it purely informational?

Comment: What technology are you using? ASP.NET?

Comment: The value won't be updated on the server side until you do a postback. Are you checking the value after doing a postback?

Comment: Yes I am checking the value after postback.

Comment: Have you checked out my answer per chance? I feel like it should do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always "un-disable" the field before posting.  E.g.,

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).find(':input:disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

And of course using `readonly` fields, as per Knix's answer, may be a viable solution as well.

---

Edit: just read your comment on Knix's answer, so it sounds like dynamically removing the disabled attribute before posting may be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think disabled fields will get posted.

Maybe you should try `readonly` field: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

```
<input id="firstName" name="firstName" value="hello world" READONLY>
```

You can always use CSS to make the readonly field appear disabled =)

EDIT:

Ok..if you cannot do the readonly, how about using AJAX to post and directly passing over the data since you say you can access it on the client side:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "yourForm.php",  // sorry I used PHP in this example 
      type: "POST",
      data: { txtCity : $('#txtCity').val() },
      success: function(msg){
         alert(msg);
      }
   }
)
```

EDIT2:

How about populating a hidden field and using that value on the server-side since you cannot use readonly fields or use AJAX?

```
$('#hiddenField').val('Naperville');
```

Since this field is hidden, the user would not know the difference =)

EDIT3:

OP got this to work using correct server-side syntax for the readonly inputs:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("readonly","readonly")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex. But I am afraid I have to use Disabled not readonly. Can you please suggest any alternate solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm...are you using AJAX for the post?

Comment: I don't think there many options left.  Using a hidden field to keep track is one idea (see EDIT2) and also jmar777's idea of removing the disabled attribute might the only options left.

Comment: The problem with HiddenField is I am using the same control in three different ways..so I cannot get use Hidden value..because it always contains the last value

Comment: How about jmar777's suggestion? That should work. I honestly do not think you have many options left. Seems you are pretty restricted with what you can do.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3415/discussion-between-user788312-and-knix)